# the value property of my input doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of my input by the following simple code but nothing is printed in **result **box.

```
<body>
<div id="result" style="height:100px"></div>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<script>
let inp = document.getElementById('inp');
let result = document.getElementById('result');
result.textContent = inp.value;
</script>
</body>
```

I was expecting that whatever I enter in the input box, is printed in result box.

Comment: .value is the value at THAT moment. It does not keep on auto updating. You need to code that with event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for the [`"input"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) to get notified each time the value changes.

Currently, you are reading the `value` only once, on page load when the user has not entered anything yet.

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('inp');
let result = document.getElementById('result');
inp.addEventListener('input', e => result.textContent = inp.value);
```

```html
<div id="result" style="height:100px"></div>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

Comment: You're right. It worked as you said. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `oninput`(Whatever I enter in the input box) method:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('inp');
let result = document.getElementById('result');

inp.oninput = function() {
  result.textContent = inp.value;
}
```

```html
<div id="result" style="height:100px"></div>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="inp">
```